# I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux/4.10.2. What server is it running?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, node.js

When I ssh into the EC2 instance and look around the server configuration files, I see Apache config files, NGINX config files. Why are both servers there? Which one takes priority? Do both servers run simultaneously? Do they work together? Where would my server side code go for Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure out which one is running you can run `ps ax | grep -E '(apache2|httpd|nginx)'` and see what comes out.

Comment: Thanks, I did it and got this:    
`>     3510 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -g daemon off;
 
>     3517 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process

>     6272 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto -E (apache2|httpd|nginx)` I do not what it means though. It looks like Nginx as I expected. But why is there apache config files in the instance is what I was getting at.

Comment: Cool, so now you know whether you’re running Apache or Nginx. Question answered :)